# How to replace many types of words at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-word

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> will pop-up a menu **FIND** and **REPLACE**. I do use this regularly but sometimes it can be frustrating that I need to do it one by one.

Consider that you have a page in Word and there is section for NAME and AGE. Now, if the page, lets say has name ALEX and age 10, I want to replace it with Carl and 20. So, I do use FIND ALEX and REPLACE CARL. Then, do the same for the age.

**Question, is there a method where I can replace both name and age simultaneously such as FIND ALEX & 10, then REPLACE CARL & 10.**

Comment: Is it always the same substitutions every time?

Comment: No, Word find & replace is pretty basic. You will need to write a VBA macro to do that, but the time you will spend writing it will be much more than your savings on these few key-strokes.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but is not native to Word. It would require writing a vba procedure (macro), not recording it. For two items, this is overkill. Greg Maxey wrote a free Add-In that does this. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html